# Is there any way to disable automatic head parking of a HDD?

Tags: hard-drive, power-management

My hard drive semms to park its head after X minutes, and when I access it again it loads the head in a fraction of a second (causing a small beep),and causing disturbances to media streamed from it. Since I'm in a critical environment where I record sound, I wonder if I can **totally disable this head parking function?** The HDD in question is a Toshiba DT01ACA300 64MB 3TB.

I have tried: Disable APM and AMM, with no change. Normally run Windows 8, but the same problem seems to show under Linux on the same machine.

I could probably use something like [KeepAliveHD](http://keepalivehd.codeplex.com/) ... but would prefer another solution. Also, having tried KeepAliveHD, it actually seems like it doesn't help. I can say why, maybe in some way the cash of the drive makes the drive not write the file directly, so that the drive can stay in standby mode?

Comment: This is your like 5th question about what appears to be a failing HDD you have messing with you.  Just replace it already! :)

Comment: There are at least three mechanisms that park the heads: power management in Windows, power management in the drive itself (green drives), and auto head parking for platter protection in the drive itself.  Your first step is to figure out what is parking the heads if you want to control that, or use a "keep alive" mechanism, which doesn't care what the source is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows power settings don't affect the built-in head parking function of the hard drive. However, it does work to use [`hdparm`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hdparm)'s `-S` and `-B` options to disable it. This solution works, but `hdparm` has to be run again after each power cycle.

A side note: Using KeepAliveHD doesn't work. That program is supposed to keep the drive awake by writing a small text file to it every minute. Maybe it doesn't work because the file is too small and stored in the cache of the drive?

Comment: What is hdparm? how to use it? what is this answer?

Comment: @kuhaku, `hdparm` is a Linux command to read and set hard disk parameters. I found a port to Windows as well, and could use that to solve my problem. See link in post to read more about `hdparm`. Cheers!

Comment: Where is the port?

Comment: And how did you use it to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

This is for Windows 7, but should more or less apply completely to Windows 8.

Start menu > Power Options > Change Plan Settings > Change Advanced Power Settings > Hard Disk (second from the top) > Turn Off Disk After > type as many 9's as will fit, or whatever you want.

Comment: The question is about a different problem.  Head parking is done internally by the drive to protect the platters.  Power off is an OS function (also done internally on green drives), to save power.

Comment: I didn't know OP was asking about a firmware way to do that, that's interesting tho.